# Android layout for drop downlist

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a drop down list in the web site with long content. The default behavior when you select the drop down list is, it pops out in the screen. My issue is when I view that on an android phone to select an item from the drop down list, some of the content is hidden (e.g It only shows 3 words of the drop down list items that are 6 words long).

Is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
u can use LinearLayout layout .

  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">MyAndroidApp</string>
    <string name="country_prompt">Choose a country</string>

    <string-array name="country_arrays">
        <item>Malaysia</item>
        <item>United States</item>
        <item>Indonesia</item>
        <item>France</item>
        <item>Italy</item>
        <item>Singapore</item>
        <item>New Zealand</item>
        <item>India</item>
    </string-array>

</resources>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:entries="@array/country_arrays"
        android:prompt="@string/country_prompt" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSubmit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this is not a dropdown list, its a textview inside a linear layout. Two different things.

Comment: Its not actually an android app... its a website